# eval: line 159: unexpected EOF while looking for matching error on gitlab pipeline

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

when i try to run the gitlab pipeline its failed and shows the eval: line 159: unexpected EOF while looking for matching error on gitlab pipeline this error

```yaml
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy-uat
   
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\GitLab-Runner\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
  TEST_TOOL_EXE: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe'

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - 'env:NUGET_PATH" restore'
    - echo "Clean & Build Solution"
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" .\Solution1.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=.\bin\publish /clp:ErrorsOnly'    
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 days
    paths:
      - "**/bin"
      - "**/obj"
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main")
```

can you help me to slove this error

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what shell your runner is using here, but I suspect the (immediate) issue is because you have unbalanced quotation marks in your job script steps. For example:

```
    - 'env:NUGET_PATH" restore'
```

The `"` is unmatched.

Comment: can you give me any sample script

Comment: currently i am using PWSH ,can you give me any sample script which i edit and check

Comment: Now i am using PWSH shell when i run the pipeline with above script its show below error

Comment: eval: line 158: syntax error near unexpected token `&'